# Application stops unexpectedly when adMob code is added to libGDX android app

Tags: android, crash, libgdx, admob

I am trying to add adMob ads to my android game created through libGDX. I followed the following tutorial: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx

My application crashes. Here is my code.

```
protected AdView adView;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            // Create the layout
                RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

            // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

            // Create the libgdx View
                AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
                cfg.useGL20 = true;
                View gameView = initializeForView(new TBGame(), cfg);

            // Create and setup the AdMob view
                AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.IAB_BANNER, adMobID); 
                adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

            // Add the libgdx view
                layout.addView(gameView);

            // Add the AdMob view
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

                layout.addView(adView, adParams);

            // Hook it all up
                setContentView(layout);

}
```

I tried to debug and found that crash occurs at

AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.IAB_BANNER, adMobID);

Can anyone tell where am i going wrong.

Comment: There should be an exception stacktrace in the logcat. Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have called initializeForView() which calls setContentView with its own view (very poor API IMO) and then you call setContentView() and replace it with your own view.

You can only have one ContentView.

It appears that that guide is totally broken.